# How do I access the test reports from an AWS CodeBuild build?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

If my tests fail then the build container is discarded?

Short of copying the test reports output into an S3 bucket every build, is there any easy way to see what tests failed and why?

Comment: I tried adding a "finally" block in the build phase of the buildspec.yml, thinking that the report directory would still be available, but the linux instance still says the report directory does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be to output the test results to `STDOUT`. This will cause them to be included in the CloudWatch Logs for the build, viewable on the AWS Console or via the API, without any additional uploads.

Comment: Oddly whilst when I build locally the Gradle output is captured, it isn't in CodeBuild, so fixing that would be a start. But JUnit creates a lovely HTML test reports structure, detailing which tests were run, and details of failure, that CodeBuild just doesn't think I should be able to see

Answer (score 0):

You mention using JUnit in a comment: with JUnit you can actually generate an html report of the tests; you can then zip the report folder and upload somewhere (most probably s3) and retrieve it after the container shuts down.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that comes under the heading of "copying the test reports output into an S3 bucket every build"